# Name field does not reflect Add profile in Admin in Django

Tags: python, django

I am a newbee to django and I have created a simple model with two fields to create profiles and registered them in admin.

here is my model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 1200)
    description = models.TextField(default= 'description default')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and below is the  admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .models import profile

class profileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model= profile

admin.site.register(profile,profileAdmin)
```

but when  I add profiles it is not showing the name of the profile

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, you should define `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`.

```
class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 1200)
    description = models.TextField(default= 'description default')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: that did it!! thank you, suggest me some blog to follow  python and django updates

Comment: Glad it worked. Sorry, I don't have any recommendations for python/django blogs.